# Create query to get count of uncompleted calls

Tags: mysql, sql, join, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

There is table waiter_log as

```
+---------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
| call_id | queue_num_curr | ast_num_curr | proceed_wait |
+---------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
| f27de4f | 9010           | 2            |            1 |
| f27de4f | 9002           | 5            |            1 |
| f27de4f | 9003           | 1            |            0 | 
| asdf231 | 9010           | 2            |            1 |
| asdf231 | 9002           | 5            |            1 |
| rete125 | 9010           | 2            |            1 |
| rete125 | 9009           | 5            |            1 |
| a7rf5gs | 9003           | 2            |            1 |
| a7rf5gs | 9006           | 5            |            1 |
| a7rf5gs | 9009           | 1            |            0 |
| qawe234 | 9003           | 2            |            1 |
| qawe234 | 9008           | 5            |            1 |
| qawe234 | 9004           | 1            |            0 |
| 49c43ad | 9004           | 2            |            1 |
| 49c43ad | 9007           | 5            |            1 |
+---------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Call with call-id 'f27de4f' started in 9010 and finished in 9003 because there is a record with proceed_wait = 0 for call-id='f27de4f'
Call with call-id 'asdf231' started in 9010, still proceed in 9002 and not finished yet because  there is no record with proceed_wait = 0 for call-id='asdf231'
Similarly for call with call-id 'rete125' there is no record with  proceed_wait = 0 and this call is not completed too.
So,for queue 9010  query result should be 2 (count of uncompleted calls)
For 9003 result should be 0 , because all calls for 9003 ('a7rf5gs' and 'qawe234') are completed.
For 9004 result should be 1 because there is no record with  proceed_wait = 0  for call with call-id '49c43ad'.

How to create a query to get count on uncompleted calls as:

```
queue_num   count 
9010         2
9004         1
```

***UPD:***
Here i updated my question
[Create query to get count of uncompleted calls group by 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904522/create-query-to-get-count-of-uncompleted-calls-group-by-2-fields)

Comment: Why isn't the count 3 at 9001? I think `asdf231`, `f27de4f`, and `rete125` are all started but not completed at that queue num.

Comment: Because for f27de4f : 9001- 9002-9003 - 9003 has proceed_wait - 0 . So f27de4f is compelted. asdf231:  9001 -9002 , rete125: 9001-9010 . Both 9002 and 9010 has no proceed_wait = 0

Comment: Aha - I was assuming the queue_num was like a timestamp, and you wanted to know how many uncompleted calls there were at each timestamp. But you have changed the data a little, so my assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another method that works without correlated subqueries or window functions:

For each row `w1`, try to find another row `w2` with the same call_id and a 0 indicating the call is complete. Using a LEFT OUTER JOIN, we can test for cases where no `w2` row exists for a given call_id.

Then do another join to a hypothetical row `w3` with the same call_id and a lesser ast_num_curr value. Again, using outer join, we can check that no such row exists. This means `w1` must have the least value for ast num for that call_id.

```
SELECT w1.call_id, w1.queue_num_curr
FROM waiter_log AS w1
LEFT OUTER JOIN waiter_log AS w2
  ON w1.call_id = w2.call_id AND w2.proceed_wait = 0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN waiter_log AS w3
  ON w1.call_id = w3.call_id AND w1.ast_num_curr > w3.ast_num_curr
WHERE w2.call_id IS NULL AND w3.call_id IS NULL;
```

Output:

```
+---------+----------------+
| call_id | queue_num_curr |
+---------+----------------+
| 49c43ad |           9004 |
| asdf231 |           9010 |
| rete125 |           9010 |
+---------+----------------+
```

To get the counts per queue_num_curr, wrap the query above in a derived-table subquery, and do the count in the outer query:

```
SELECT queue_num_curr, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT w1.call_id, w1.queue_num_curr
  FROM waiter_log AS w1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN waiter_log AS w2
    ON w1.call_id = w2.call_id AND w2.proceed_wait = 0
  LEFT OUTER JOIN waiter_log AS w3
    ON w1.call_id = w3.call_id AND w1.ast_num_curr > w3.ast_num_curr
  WHERE w2.call_id IS NULL AND w3.call_id IS NULL
) AS t
GROUP BY queue_num_curr;
```

Output:

```
+----------------+-------+
| queue_num_curr | count |
+----------------+-------+
|           9004 |     1 |
|           9010 |     2 |
+----------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with window functions:

```
select 
    min_queue_num_curr queue_num_curr,
    count(*) cnt
from (
    select 
        proceed_wait ,
        row_number() over(partition by call_id order by queue_num_curr desc) rn,
        min(queue_num_curr) over(partition by call_id) min_queue_num_curr
    from mytable
) t
where rn = 1 and proceed_wait = 1
group by min_queue_num_curr
```

The subquery retrives the starting `queue_num_curr` of each `call_id` and ranks the records of each call. The outer query filters on the last record par call and on unfinished calls, and aggregates by starting `queue_num_curr`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3a228bed753daf1f9a18801974dc92d5)**:

```
queue_num_curr | cnt
-------------: | --:
          9001 |   2
          9003 |   1
          9004 |   1
```

NB: call `a7rf5gs` started on `queue_num_curr = 9003` and had `proceed_wait = 1` on `queue_num_curr = 9009`, so it should be considered unfinished too.

---

In earlier versions, you can self-join the table to get the starting `queue_num_cur` of each call, and use a correlated subquery to filter on the last record per call id. Then you can filter on unfinished records and aggregate by starting `queue_num_cur`:

```
select tmin.queue_num_curr, count(*)
from mytable t
inner join (
    select call_id, min(queue_num_curr) queue_num_curr from mytable group by call_id
) tmin on tmin.call_id = t.call_id
where 
    t.queue_num_curr = (
    select max(t1.queue_num_curr) from mytable t1 where t1.call_id = t.call_id
    )
    and t.proceed_wait = 1
group by tmin.queue_num_curr
order by tmin.queue_num_curr
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=01b4e375db1e6f1dfc731bf56a302719)**

Comment: Thanks, GMB. But i have 5 version.

Comment: @harp1814: I edited my version with a solution for MySQL < 8.0

Comment: GMB, 
Call-id a7rf5gs  has proceed_wait = 0   on   9009 , so it is considered as completed

Comment: `For 9003 result should be 0` your query returns 1 … 

Comment: @Luuk: yes I explained that in my answer: *call a7rf5gs started on queue_num_curr = 9003 and had proceed_wait = 1 on queue_num_curr = 9009, so it should be considered unfinished too.* So I think that's a glitch in your expected results.

Comment: GMB, i edited my question. The first queue number for call-id  may be greater than second one.

Comment: @harp1814: if is not a good practice to substantially edit a question after answers were posted... For this, you usually want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the logic correctly (I'm not certain on that), you can `GROUP BY` the queue and `count()` the distinct call IDs for which no record with `proceed_wait = 0` exists, which can be queried via a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT wl1.queue_num_curr,
       count(DISTINCT
             (SELECT wl1.call_id
                     FROM dual
                     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                              FROM waiter_log wl2
                                              WHERE wl2.call_id = wl1.call_id
                                                    AND wl2.proceed_wait = 0))) count
       FROM waiter_log wl1
       GROUP BY wl1.queue_num_curr;
```

If `(call_id, queue_num_curr)` is unique, i.e. no call can appear more than one time in a queue, that can be simplified to just take the `sum()` of the `NOT EXISTS` (because Boolean expressions are mapped to 0 (for false) or 1 (for true) in numeric context).

```
SELECT wl1.queue_num_curr,
       sum(NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                              FROM waiter_log wl2
                                   WHERE wl2.call_id = wl1.call_id
                                         AND wl2.proceed_wait = 0)) count
       FROM waiter_log wl1
       GROUP BY wl1.queue_num_curr;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c58184c7f273a9bb50269f64505a8ad6)